# Hoes does the code get transpiled to javascript in a project created using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

Hoes does the code get transpiled to javascript in a project created using create-react-app  --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts? Does it use Babel/Webpack? I have checked package.json but no mention of any such dependency.

Comment: [`create-react-app-typescript` uses Webpack with the Babel loader for JavaScript files](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/blob/e4b1f9424fa14f7aae7f0cbf5fd64e18dd273527/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L160), and [`ts-loader` for TypeScript files](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/blob/e4b1f9424fa14f7aae7f0cbf5fd64e18dd273527/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L174).

Answer (score 2):

`react-scripts*` is just a wrapper for common configs.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L346) it uses babel-loader to convert from js/jsx to es5. Also uses ts-loader to compile from ts to js.

Answer (score 0):

yes, with babel:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-scripts/package.json

the code for compilation is in `react-scripts`